# h1, h2, h3.. elements eats div margins

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

Why h1, h2, h3 elements margins are ignored when in div?

http://jsfiddle.net/TzmdZ/

```
<div class="col">
    <h3>This is header</h3>
</div>  
<div class="col">
    <h3>This is header</h3>
</div>

.col {
    background: gray;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.col h3 {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

When I put h element into div and there is no other text in it, though h element and div element bottom margins are spicified, h bottom margin is ignored.

Comment: this is the correct behaviour, what you want is to give your `col` class a `padding-bottom: 1em;`

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to do... but maybe you are trying to do a padding: check `padding-bottom: 1em;` instead.

Comment: you try to ignored bottom margin set the  margin-top:-18px; in .col css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assigning margins to two siblings will cause the margins to collapse where the margins are adjacent.

This [MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing) explains the situation in detail.

> Top and bottom margins of blocks are sometimes combined (collapsed)
>   into a single margin whose size is the largest of the margins combined
>   into it, a behavior known as margin collapsing.

**Margin collapsing occurs in three basic cases:**

1. Adjacent Siblings
2. Parent and first/last child
3. Empty blocks

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS:

```
.col {
    background: gray;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.col h3 {
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}
```

Change `margin-bottom` to `padding-bottom`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mareebsiddiqui/TzmdZ/4/)